# Asp.Net Core Javascript not working with Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having trouble with an javascript file on ASP .NET Core 2.0. I'm doing a course to learn ASP .NET Core, and my javascript file doesn't wants to work, I don't know why, it doesn't appears on network and it doesn't shows any console.log that I try to use.

The file is located at wwwroot/js and I have the @section with the script included on the view. I already compared my code with the final project and there's nothing wrong.

What I've tried so far is: resetting browser cache, putting the script on the layout.cshtml, but no results. I also tried to do some other stuff that I found here and nothing worked.

Comment: How about inspecting the _rendered_ HTML? Have you done any browser based dev tools inspection? Any request errors shown in the browser dev tool? Syntax errors? Nobody here can _guess_ given what's in your question....

Comment: Well, you need to include at least the console log and debugging results to know what kind of problem you have, because JS scripts executed in client-side.

Comment: I tried to call the debugger and it didn't worked, and no errors on console dev tool on chrome as well, sorry for not saying that I've already checked it, I forgot. It's behaving like the javascript file doesn't even exists or something. Everything was working until I put the javascript code in a separated file. I also tried to get the values on the data variable, no results. Here is a fiddle from the view and the javascript code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3ame6fy9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed my problem, the issue was happening because there were 2 csproj on the same folder, and I was running the one without the javascript file, what a dumb mistake. Thanks for everyone that tried to help me anyway.